# Disabling automatic build in NetBeans

Tags: ide, netbeans

I am using Netbeans IDE 6.7.1 and I wish to disable the automatic build feature. Or somehow change the priority of this automatic build thread. Its always building, and slow down my computer alot. I think because of this, at times, Netbeans takes around 80% of my CPU.
I dont really want this feature, I can do a build when I want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rightclick the project name -> Properties -> Build -> Compiling. There you can uncheck "Compile on save" option (if you use Ant) or select "Disable" (if you use Maven).