# Java NoSuchMethodError in enum

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation, enums, nosuchmethoderror

I just added a method to an enum. Whenever I invoke that method I get a NoSuchMethodError:

```
public enum PHASE {
  PHASE1,
  PHASE2(false),
  PHASE3;

  private boolean present = true;

  PHASE() {
  }

  PHASE(boolean present) {
    this.present = present;
  }

  public boolean isPresent() {
    return this.present;
  }
}

public void foo(PHASE phase) {
  if (phase.isPresent()) {
...
```

Here phase.isPresent throws a NoSuchMethodError after clean/build. What am I missing?

--

UPDATE: Netbeans has two cache folders. One was empty, the other one was not. That is my bad, apparently I didn't put enough effort into the caching issue. Unfortunately I cannot downvote my own question...

Comment: code seems fine.is it possible for you to post the whole class?

Comment: I can't reproduce your exception.

Comment: It works. Try to rebuild your project.

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I can't post the whole class because of confidentiality issues.

Comment: NetBeans 7.2, but I'm getting more and more concerned each day to return to Eclipse despite the current corporate and team policy.

Comment: can I please be informed why the question was downvoted?

Comment: @linski - presumably because the OP can't / won't provide enough information to allow other people to reproduce the problem.  (But I can't speak for the people who downvoted ...)

Comment: *"Sorry, I can't post the whole class because of confidentiality issues."* - That would not stop you creating an SSCCE with the confidential parts replaced with stubs, etcetera.

Comment: Well, I thought what mattered was already shown (ie. an enum with a method inside a class). The rest of the container class in no way interacts with the wrapped enum.

Comment: @DrH [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is a very useful practice, just linking in case you didn't know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that this is Netbeans specific issue. Especially if you use "Compile on save option" and have a big project with a lot of dependencies. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386076/uncompilable-source-code-runtimeexception-in-netbeans) for details.

I had a very similar problem with such (maven-based) project almost on a daily basis, and found a solution using the above link. Better to say variations of solution. Try it like this:

- [disable compile on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304149/disabling-automatic-build-in-netbeans)
- close the problematic project
- close netbeans
- [clear cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/clearing-cache-in-netbeans)
- open netbeans and clean&build

please feedback.

Comment: Thank you, I already have the ScanOnDemand plugin added as due to a known issue 7.2's background scan can fall into an infinite loop (already fixed in 7.2.1, I just haven't got the time to upgrade yet). This by default disables the compile on save feature, so after each modification I always run a full clean/build before starting the next debug session.

The cache folder is empty (has been empty for weeks, which is also a bit odd).

Comment: yes, that's definetley odd. Whenever I looked at it, regardless of options, it always had something. Hm. Is it a maven project?

Comment: No, plain old Java project checked out via SVN.

Comment: you might wanna try running the project via ant from command line, it should do less processing that way if I remeber correctly. If you find a solution please feedback. PS I moved to eclipse because it got to irritating after some time. Now I got irritated by it too, so I'm moving to IDEA :)

Answer (score 4):

This is probably an issue between your compile-time classpath and you run-time classpath.
Your classes/jars files at runtime are not the same that you used at compile time.

Clean and rebuild your project to be sure.

Comment: I already have, at least a dozen times. `if (phase.present)` works neither, in this case a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: MyClass$ERASE_PHASE.access$000(LMyClass$ERASE_PHASE;)Z` is thrown.

Comment: Thank you, I take a look at the compile and runtime classpath differences, whether any.

Comment: What if you try to use a different IDE. It might be an issue about your IDE. You can try to clear manually the generated classes and check the file generated (with a java decompiler you will be able to check the differences)

Comment: @TheEwook - I would use `javap` for that.